# Slim 4 php-di Factory function not running as expected / not "fully" called

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim, php-di, slim-4

i'm having problems registering a factory causing a strange behaviour.

When my dependency is resolved by the factory function i can see (by testing..), that actually only the constructor is called, nothing more.

Here's the factory function + DI definition:

```
AuthStrategySelectorInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $container): AuthStrategySelector {
    $authStrategySelector = new AuthStrategySelector();
    $authStrategySelector
      ->register($container->get(JwtAuthStrategy::class));
    return $authStrategySelector;
  }
```

And heres the behaviour i can see, but i don't understand:
It seems like the `register`-function never gets called.. I also confirmed that by just writing something like `die('test');` behind the instantiation of `$authStrategySelector`.

I can't see any error inside the logs, etc. and i wrapped my head around that problem since like 2 hours..

And i tested every other involved component like the AuthStrategy, which is even empty for testing..

Comment: Did you declared AuthStrategySelectorInterface as dependency in a class constructor?

Comment: Yeah, i‘m currently writing test cases which actually work for the same di container. I‘m really clueless :/..